# Focus a TextBox by pressing any key

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an `UserControl` that contains some controls and a `TextBox`. When the user press any key, I want to focus on this `TextBox`.

How can I do this, if I'm working with MVVM and WPF?

Comment: Keep in the view then. Focus belongs to view and your view model should not care which control has the focus

Comment: Hi @dkozl and how can I do this?

Comment: I tried to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795683/how-can-i-focus-textbox-in-xaml-with-keybinding and didn't work

Comment: Has absolutely nothing to do with MVVM.  Use your codebehind in the UserControl to manage focus.

Comment: Do it in the codebehind of the view, MVVM is only a guideline. Functionality that only has impact on the View should be in implemented in xaml, or if not possible in the codebehind...

Comment: Ok. I added: KeyUp="myTestKey" to UserControl and in my view.cs added:         private void myTestKey(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) but I'm losing usercontrol focus, it's just firing if I click on textbox, and type something, for example

Comment: It's working using a Loaded function that adds the keyup event!

Comment: A more generic and reusable way to do this by creating an Interactivity Action or Attached Behaviour